# Elementary OS try or install

Tags: system-installation, install

I've been trying to install elementary OS on my computer, I did a boot pen drive it's alright, but when computer starts to install elementary OS, computer show me "elementary OS next elementary tty1" and asked me login and password, ofcourse I didn't install the OS how I have a login and password, I'm confuse about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this is a bug and it happens to me as well and I have not yet found a solution. Can you tell me what computer you are installing on, e.g. is it a laptop or a desktop, how old is it, do you know which graphics card and motherboard it has?

I found that the username is 'elementary' and there is no password, but this will not help you much unless you are an experienced Linux user.